# Unable to display content in modal using ajax and codeigniter

Tags: json, ajax, codeigniter, post, modal-dialog

Hi i've been struggling trying to display data on a modal based on an id. But somehow the data sent from the controller is not displayed in the modal, I've tried all and I couldn't figure what is wrong with my code.
Ps. sorry for my english, it's not my native language.

1 Here is my script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.test_data',function(){
      var idemp = $(this).attr("id");
      $.ajax({
          url : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Test/cargarevaluado",
          method : "POST",
          data : {idemp : idemp},
          datatype : "json",
          success : function(data) {

            $('#evaluacion').modal('show');
            $('#nom').val(data.puesto);
            $('#apel').val(data.sueldo);
          }
      });
    });
  });
```

2 This is my controller.

```
public function cargarevaluado(){
  $id = $this->input->post('idemp');
  $this->load->model('testModel');
  $empleado = $this->testModel->loademp($id);
  echo json_encode($empleado);
}
```

3. My model is just a standard database query.
4. This is my modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="evaluacion" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" >
              <input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" >
              <input type="text" name="apel" id="apel" >
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

5 And finally this is the button from which I collect the ID from the foreach function.

```
<td><button type="button"  name="evaluar" id="<?php echo $e->idEmpleado; ?>" class="btn btn-danger test_data">Evaluar</button></td>
```

Any help or any suggestions will be gladly accepted. I really need to pass data to modals, which will help me through the development of my school project.

Comment: are you familiar with developer tools? with the page open, open dev tools in chrome and go to the network tab. click the button `evaluar` and you will see a new request going to your `cargarevaluado` function. view the response in the tab; is it what you expect? if not, what is it?

Comment: Yes and i see a response containing the values of the employee from the database. Have a look [{"idEmpleado":"1","activo":"1","fechaingreso":"2016-09-04","fechabaja":null,"hentrada":"09:00:00","hsalida":"18:00:00","diasinhabiles":"0","sueldo":"50000.00","puesto":"jefe rh","tipocontrato":"6 meses","evaluado":"0","departamento_iddepartamento":"1"}]

Comment: well the keys `sueldo` and `puesto` are there. maybe try this format `$('element').val(newValue).trigger('change');`